# replace list of strings using dictionary

Tags: python

I have python code

```
my_list = ['hsdpa_-_rl_fail', 'avg_reported_cqi.', 'fach-c_load_ratio', 'canc_isho_cpich/ecno_nrt_m1010c209']
my_dict = {'-' : 'dash' , '.':'dot' , '/':'slash'}
```

I want search and replace in my_list as per mapping given in my_dict that is my_dict key shall be replaced by respective value in all element of my_list.

How this can be done in pythonic way?

Comment: what have you tried yet?

Comment: don't try anything, start by a google search

Comment: tried using loops ..I think I got it from google . thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple Iteration.

**Ex:**

```
my_list = ['hsdpa_-_rl_fail', 'avg_reported_cqi.', 'fach-c_load_ratio', 'canc_isho_cpich/ecno_nrt_m1010c209']
my_dict = {'-' : 'dash' , '.':'dot' , '/':'slash'}

for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    for k in my_dict:
        if k in v:
            my_list[i] = v.replace(k, my_dict[k])

print(my_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['hsdpa_dash_rl_fail', 'avg_reported_cqidot', 'fachdashc_load_ratio', 'canc_isho_cpichslashecno_nrt_m1010c209']
```